# OpenMP '#pragma omp parallel for ' in '#pragmaomp section'

Tags: openmp

I want to parallelize the loop in each section, but this seems not feasible.
Can you explain how to implement it?
Thanks！

```
`#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(10)
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
            vector<int> a(5);
#pragma     omp parallel for 
            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
                a[i] = i;
            }
        }
#pragma omp section
        {
            vector<int> b(5);
#pragma     omp parallel for 
            for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
                b[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result of the code mentioned above is always 0.

Comment: You need nested parallelism for that. Just remove the `num_threads(10)` clause in your first `parallel` directive, and set the following environment variable while launching your code: `OMP_NUM_THREADS='2,5'`

Comment: Is the use of OpenMP sections required in your code, or is just a solution you have imagined to be able to run two loops in parallel? I mean, couldn't you just suppress the sections here?

Comment: Thank you. I added omp_set_nested() , and set the environment variable: OMP_ NESTED=TRUE, this Problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to run each iteration of 2 different loops in parallel is using tasks. I suggest the following structure:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
    for(...) //first for loop
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            //loop body to run parallel
        }
    }

    for(...) //second for loop
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            //loop body to run parallel
        }
    }
}
```

Note that

1. The OpenMP runtime/compiler may decide not to defer the task, but run it immediately by the encountering thread. (The workload in your example is very small, so this may happen.)
2. You have to make sure that the loop body is thread-safe and that the sharing attributes of all your variables are correctly set up. (e.g. `cout` is not thread-safe in your example)

Comment: Thank you. I added omp_set_nested() , and set the environment variable: OMP_ NESTED=TRUE, this Problem can be solved.

Comment: you can also use `taskloop` construct above the loop instead of explicitly creating a task for each iteration

Comment: @648trindade Indeed, as I mentioned it is one of the possible solutions. In this case, you have to use the `nogroup` clause as well.